# Usage of *what* for *that* or *than* in BrE

Tags: british-english, word-usage, what-that

Occasionally, when watching British television or movies, I've come across a construct that isn't used in AmE.

Using *what* as a replacement for *that* or *than* as a determiner or comparison.

Here is an example from the classic [Monty Python Parrot Sketch](http://www.davidpbrown.co.uk/jokes/monty-python-parrot.html):

> C: Never mind that, my lad. I wish to complain about this parrot **what** I purchased not half an hour ago from this very boutique.
>
> O: Oh yes, the, uh, the Norwegian Blue...What's,uh...What's wrong with it?
>
> C: I'll tell you what's wrong with it, my lad. 'E's dead, that's what's wrong with it!

In AmE we would always say *... parrot **that** I purchased ...*

I've also heard it used as a replacement for than in a comparison:

> He thinks he's got bigger balls, **what** I got!

I'm guessing that in this case it's merely a colloquial deletion of *than* and should be *than what I've got*.

**My question:  Is this considered a colloquial usage in BrE?  Or is it fairly standard in the Queen's English?**

It seems to me that it might be colloquial based upon John Cleese's accent and intonation, but I don't have the ear for the British accent to pinpoint a regional vs. a socio-economic class of accent.

Comment: It is certainly not Queen's English, more an impersonation of a Cockney accent. Accent impressions are a constant feature of conversational English where people will imitate a voice to convey an impression of the type of person to whom they are referring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It is certainly not Queen's English, more an impersonation of a
>   Cockney accent. Accent impressions are a constant feature of
>   conversational English where people will imitate a voice to convey an
>   impression of the type of person to whom they are referring

I agree with WS2 up to a point, The incorrect use of *what* in place of *that* is certainly not a feature of the "Queen's English" but knowing the parrot sketch like the back of my hand, I'd say that John Cleese was not speaking with a Cockney accent but with a stereotypical RP accent. A parody of those who disguise their low social class by faking a *posh accent*, i.e. [Received Pronunciation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_structure_of_the_United_Kingdom#Accent_and_language_and_social_class). It is the shop keeper played by Michael Palin who speaks [Cockney](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockney#Cockney_speech).

John Cleese's character is all the funnier because he is such an obvious dim wit; a customer who doesn't realize he's bought a dead parrot until it falls off its perch, who completely misunderstands the "foreign" word *boutique*, and yet uses clichè high register expressions and words — *purchase* instead of *buy* — correctly.

> "I wish to complain about this parrot **what** I purchased not half an
>   hour ago from **this very boutique**."

The use of *what* or *wot* in BrEng speech is a well-known marker of social status and level of education.  And the dropping of g's and h's in one's speech is yet another common feature of Cockney.

> Look, **I took the liberty of examining** that parrot when I got it home, [...]  **'E's** not **pinin'**! **'E's** passed on! This parrot is no more! He has ceased to be! '**E's expired** and gone to meet its maker!

It is this bizarre combination of standard and nonstandard English that might mislead one into thinking the use of *what* as a relative pronoun to be acceptable. This mixing of styles used to be typical among lower-class Britons [wishing to be associated with a certain class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sociolinguistics#Class_aspiration). It is worth mentioning that the UK used to be obsessed with social class system until the mid/late 1970s and today that particular form of *dialect* or *speaking style* is becoming rarer (that at least is my impression).

> **[Language and Social Class](http://users.ox.ac.uk/~romaine/isb309114.pdf)**
>   Linguists have known for some time that diﬀerences in language are tied to social class. Ross (1954)
>   suggested that certain lexical and phonological diﬀerences in English
>   could be classified as U (upper class) or non-U (lower class), e.g.,
>   serviette (non-U) vs. table-napkin (U), one of the best known of all
>   linguistic class indicators of England at the time. [...] The variable
>   (h) refers to alternation between }h} and lack of }h} in words
>   beginning with }h} such as heart, hand, etc. Unlike received
>   pronunciation (RP), most urban accents in England do not have initial
>   }h} or are variable in their usage of it. For these speakers who `drop
>   their h's,' art and heart are pronounced the same.

Answer (score 3):

That usage of *what* would be considered a colloquialism in standard British English. It is often used for effect by speakers of standard British English when imitating a speaker of a supposed (but not necessarily specified) regional dialect - just as in the John Cleese example. You will sometimes see it spelt "wot", just to make the point, for example in the phrase "wot I thunk" (ie "what I thought").

Comment: I would agree with Mari-Lou A's comment that the John Cleese Parrot example is more sophisticated that a simple imitation of an accent - it is an imitation of someone with a "lower status" accent attempting and failing to imitate a RP accent and manner of speech.