# Is using "what" in place of "that" associated with a particular dialect of English?

Tags: dialects

While watching *Mickey's Once Upon a Christmas*, I heard the character Pete say the phrase "reindeer what fly" instead of "reindeer that fly". As a native English speaker, I have never used "what" that way before, nor have I heard anyone use it that way in real life. But I have heard it on TV before, so I'm thinking it must just be a regional thing.

Is this usage of "what" found in a particular dialect/region of English? If so, which one?

Comment: It's not American, maybe East London.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Usage of \*what\* for \*that\* or \*than\* in BrE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/162619/usage-of-what-for-that-or-than-in-bre). The answer seems to be that it's Cockney or similar.

Comment: @StuartF Yes, thank you! I'd be fine with this question being closed as a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 0):

It is an informal, nonstandard usage
[What:](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/what)

(Nonstandard) Which, who, or that: *It's the poor what gets the blame.*

Comment: Not a particular regional dialect, just general nonstandard usage (what in the past would have been termed 'uneducated').

Comment: @Kate Not closely associated with Morecambe?